# Adding a table line to the row

Tags: html, css

I  have several php generated tables like below, and I tried to add a table line on the 3rd and 4th row but I failed.

What I tried is this:

```css
table.tbc td:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: 0.12em solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<table class='tbc'>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this? I know this is an unusual table structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add a border between the 3rd and 4th `tr`s. If so, the right selector is `table.tbc tr:nth-child(3) td`

```css
table.tbc tr:nth-child(3) td {
  border-bottom: 0.12em solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<table class='tbc'>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!

Comment: Please accept the answer so it will help to other people.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was away I forgot about it.

Comment: Thanks, not problem :)